# Looking for Email Storage Service

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud-hosting, sendgrid

I'm working on a system that generates reports on servers and send them to customers as email attachments. I want to use cloud service for email delivery and email storage. For storage I need capabilities of indexing/querying.

For email delivery there are services like [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com/).
For email storage there are services like [Google App Engine](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business).

However I'm looking for 1 service that handle it all, or 2 services with minimal effort in integration. For example, for manipulating Gmail inbox I need to implement my own IMAP library with [Google's IMAP extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions.html). Also if I want a separate inbox for each customer, the price is very expensive (5$ month). So, any alternatives are welcomed...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google App Engine for both the functionalities you describe. You can store the emails in the Datastore or Blobstore and use the [Mail Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) or [Mail Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview) for email delivery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm but my system isn't running on Google App Engine and I don't want to do such migration. So to employ this approach I need to write some dedicated middle-tier GAE application only for integration purpose (This application respond to "send-mail" request, then send the mail, then store it). I wouldn't say it's minimal effort...